# How to add users to sfguard

Tags: php, symfony1, sfguard

I'm using [symfony](http://www.symfony-project.net) 1.2 with [sfguard 1.4.1](http://www.symfony-project.org/plugins/sfGuardPlugin).
What's the best practice for registering a new user on the system?

Answer (score 8):

It's:

```
symfony guard:create-user <username> <password>
```

Comment: I know this is an old issue, but for those of you like me picking up work on old system with this, the command for me was `symfony guard:create-user email name password` you can also add `--is-super-admin` to grant that user super admin permissions.

Answer (score 1):

You can use sfDoctrineApply. This plugin generates the necessary templates for creating and validating users in the frontend. It can also send emails to users to validated accounts. It's necessary to install ZendMail.