# How do I add sfguard superuser via command line? Currently I just get a PDO connection error

Tags: pdo, symfony-1.4, sfguard, root

Sorry if this is base, I don't know much about Symfony.

I'm trying to set up a fresh, live database to populate. I have copied the schema from our test server, but dont want the whole test db. This means I have no admin user to work in the backend.

What I want to do is add a super user via the command line. I found this: 
[How to add users to sfguard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/906688/how-to-add-users-to-sfguard)

But I get the following error:

```
Unable to open PDO connection [wrapped: invalid data source name]
```

Also, I don't think the user created here would be a superadmin, no?

If anyone can explain the error or how to add a superuser it would make my life a tonne better and mean I can get some actual stuff done (instead of banging my head against the keyb). Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is about PDO can not connect to your database. You should edit `config/databases.yml` and fill in your connection information correctly like:

```
all:
  doctrine:
    class: sfDoctrineDatabase
    param:
      dsn:      mysql:host=localhost;dbname=your_database_name
      username: your_username
      password: your_password #(or null if no password)
```

For more information see [databases.yml reference](http://www.symfony-project.org/reference/1_4/en/07-Databases)

To create a new user use `php symfony guard:create-user email@example.com username passwod` and than make this user super admin `php symfony guard:promote username`

Comment: Brilliant. Solved both counts. Thanks a bunch 1ed!